# Calculating available timeslots in PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following data:

```
    $businessHours = [
        ['09:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        ['14:00:00', '18:00:00'] // notice the 1 hour break
    ];

    $appointments = [
        ['10:00:00', '10:30:00'], // format is [from, until]
        ['15:30:00', '16:15:00']
    ];
```

How would I go about collecting available *15 minute* timeslots, **within** the business hours, **outside** the work break?

In aboves case, the result should be:

```
[
    ['09:00:00', '09:15:00'],
    ['09:15:00', '09:30:00'],
    ['09:30:00', '09:45:00'],
    ['09:45:00', '10:00:00'],
                               // 10:00:00 to 10:30:00 excluded (unavailable)
    ['10:30:00', '10:45:00'],
    ['10:45:00', '11:00:00'],

    ['11:00:00', '11:15:00'],
    ['11:15:00', '11:30:00'],
    ['11:30:00', '11:45:00'],
    ['11:45:00', '12:00:00'],

    ['12:00:00', '12:15:00'],
    ['12:15:00', '12:30:00'],
    ['12:30:00', '12:45:00'],
    ['12:45:00', '13:00:00'],
                                // excluded work break
    ['14:00:00', '14:15:00'],
    ['14:15:00', '14:30:00'],
    ['14:30:00', '14:45:00'],
    ['14:45:00', '15:00:00'],

    ['15:00:00', '15:15:00'],
    ['15:15:00', '15:30:00'],
                               // 15:30:00 to 16:15:00 excluded (unavailable)
    ['16:15:00', '16:30:00'],
    ['16:30:00', '16:45:00'],
    ['16:45:00', '17:00:00'],

    ['17:00:00', '17:15:00'],
    ['17:15:00', '17:30:00'],
    ['17:30:00', '17:45:00'],
    ['17:45:00', '18:00:00'],
    
];
```

Comment: I removed the `sql` tag, since this question does not seem related to databases.

Comment: @Acework Please give the result you want in the question

Comment: [Here is my answer](https://paiza.io/projects/MiukIJinrzgzPl80K0kqZg)

Answer (score 2):

The way I came up with to solve your problem is to convert your business hours and appointments arrays into a single availability array, which will contain the time slots at which you are available.

With this array, I can easily generate the array of slots you need by counting the number of slots available in a period of time, thanks to the provided slot duration (of 15 minutes in your example).

To be more clear, in your example, you have the following:

```php
$businessHours = [
  ['09:00:00', '13:00:00'],
  ['14:00:00', '18:00:00']
];

$appointments = [
  ['10:00:00', '10:30:00'],
  ['15:30:00', '16:15:00']
];
```

But I want to work with availabilities, so I need to convert `$businessHours` and `$appointments` into an `$availability` array, which should be, in this example, the following:

```php
$availability = [
  ['09:00:00', '10:00:00'],
  ['10:30:00', '13:00:00'],
  ['14:00:00', '15:30:00'],
  ['16:15:00', '18:00:00']
];
```

## Implementation

I am going to use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) for this example implementation. I am going to do a raw implementation of the functionality, then I will refactor into a proper class.

### Getting breaks

The first thing I needed was an array of breaks. A break is a period during which you are not available. For instance, between 13h00 and 14h00 because it's a business hour pause, and between 10h00 and 10h30 because of an appointment.

So, to put it simply, the breaks are a mapping of the last item of each `$businessHours`'s entry and the first item of the next one, as well as every `$appointments` entry.

Because of this, I need to create a function that returns such mapping. Here is that function:

```php
function array_end_to_next_start($array) {
  $result = [];
  $first = null;
  $last = null;
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $isFirst = $i === 0;
    $isLast = $i === count($array) - 1;

    if ($isFirst) {
      $first = $array[$i][0];
    }

    if ($isLast) {
      $last = $array[$i][1];
      continue;
    }

    $result[] = [$array[$i][1], $array[$i + 1][0]];
  }
  
  return [$result, $first, $last];
}
```

This is not a good code, but it gets the work done (and I'll refactor later). This function loops through the given array, takes it last value and the first value of the next one, and add them in another array.

Additionally, it keeps track of the first element and the last element.

Using this function on `$businessHours`, I get the following array:

```php
[
  ['13:00:00', '14:00:00']
]
```

Which is exactly what I want. Combined to `$appointments`, I now have all of the breaks:

```php
[
  ['13:00:00', '14:00:00'],
  ['10:00:00', '10:30:00'],
  ['15:30:00', '16:15:00']
]
```

You can notice how they are not in order. To fix that, I use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort by the first hour in each array:

```php
usort($breaks, fn ($a, $b) => $a[0] <=> $b[0]);
```

> **Note**: if you didn't know about it, `<=>` is the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

### Getting the availabilities

Now that we have the breaks, we can use the same pattern we used on `$businessHours` to get your availabilities.

Because you are available when you are not in break, I just have to reuse the `array_end_to_next_start` function on `$breaks` to get a mapping of the periods during which you are not in a pause nor at an appointment.

Earlier, I used it on `$businessHours` like the following:

```php
[$breaks, $startOfDay, $endOfDay] = array_end_to_next_start($businessHours);
```

Now, I will use it on `$breaks` like the following:

```php
[$availability, $first, $last] = array_end_to_next_start($breaks);
```

Thanks to these two calls, I can have a complete `$availability` array:

```php
$availability = [
  [$startOfDay, $first], 
  ...$availability,
  [$last, $endOfDay]
];
```

### Generating availability slots from a period

Now that we have what we needed, we need to think about the initial problematic: you need to get an array of slots. Earlier, I explained that you could generate it thanks to the slot duration, which is, in this case, of 15 minutes.

To do this, I will create a `generate_slot_array_from_period` function:

```php
function generate_slot_array_from_period($start, $end) {
  $slotDuration = 15;
  $start = Carbon::createFromTimeString($start);
  $end = Carbon::createFromTimeString($end);
  
  $slotCount = (int) ($start->diffInMinutes($end) / $slotDuration);
  $slots = [];
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < $slotCount; $i++) {
    $slots[] = [
      $start->format('H:i:s'),
      $start->addMinutes($slotDuration)->format('H:i:s')
    ];
  }
  
  return $slots;
}
```

The interesting part is how I get to know the amount of slots for the given starting time, by getting the difference, in minutes, between the ending time and the starting time, and by dividing that amount by the duration of the slot.

For instance, if you are free from 14:00:00 to 16:00:00, the difference in minutes between the two will be 120. Divided by 15, we know that you have 8 slots of 15 minutes of availability.

Next thing, we loop 8 times to add these periods to an array.

### Getting the slots from the availabilities

Last thing we need to do is to call `generate_slot_array_from_period` for every availability period. This is quite simple:

```php
function generate_slot_array_from_availability_array($availability) {
  $slots = [];
  
  foreach ($availability as [$start, $end]) {
    $slots = array_merge(
        $slots, 
        generate_slot_array_from_period($start, $end)
    );
  }
  
  return $slots;
}
```

This is it. When called with the `$availability` array, this function will return exactly what you wanted: an array of slots, excluding the business hour breaks and the appointments.

```php
generate_slot_array_from_availability_array($availability);
```

## Full code

### Procedural

Here is the full procedural code, the first one that I implemented to get the functionality ready: https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/jolly-sun-d875

### Object Oriented

Here is the full, cleaned up, object-oriented, fluent code that I refactorised from the procedural one: https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/quiet-snow-x2xq

#### `Calendar.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Calendar;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class Calendar
{
    protected array $businessHours;
    protected array $appointments;
    protected array $availability;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->businessHours = [];
        $this->appointments  = [];
        $this->availability  = [];
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fluent API
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public static function create(): self
    {
        return new static();
    }

    public function withBusinessHours(array $businessHours): self
    {
        $this->businessHours = $businessHours;

        return $this;
    }

    public function withAppointments(array $appointments): self
    {
        $this->appointments = $appointments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the available slots.
     */
    public function getSlots(int $duration = 15): array
    {
        $slots = [];

        foreach ($this->getAvailabilityArray() as [$start, $end]) {
            $slots = array_merge(
                $slots,
                $this->getSlotsFromPeriod(
                    Carbon::createFromTimeString($start),
                    Carbon::createFromTimeString($end),
                $duration)
            );
        }

        return $slots;
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Helpers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected function formatDate(Carbon $date, string $format = 'H:i:s'): string
    {
        return $date->format($format);
    }

    /**
     * Maps the end of each item to the start of the next one.
     *
     * @return array Returns an array which contains, in order, the new mapped array,
     */
    protected function mapArrayEndToStart($array): array
    {
        $result    = [];
        $itemCount = count($array);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; ++$i) {
            $isLast = $i === $itemCount - 1;

            if ($isLast) {
                continue;
            }

            $result[] = [
                $array[$i][1],
                $array[$i + 1][0],
            ];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets an array containing the availability slots.
     */
    protected function getAvailabilityArray(): array
    {
        $breaks = [
            ...$this->mapArrayEndToStart($this->businessHours),
            ...$this->appointments,
        ];

        usort($breaks, fn ($a, $b) => $a[0] <=> $b[0]);

        $availability = [
            [
                $this->businessHours[0][0],
                $breaks[0][0],
            ],
            ...$this->mapArrayEndToStart($breaks),
            [
                $breaks[count($breaks) - 1][1],
                $this->businessHours[count($this->businessHours) - 1][1],
            ],
        ];

        return $availability;
    }

    /**
     * Gets an array of slots of the format [slotStartTime, slotEndTime] for the given time period.
     */
    protected function getSlotsFromPeriod(Carbon $start, Carbon $end, int $slotDuration = 15): array
    {
        $count = (int) ($start->diffInMinutes($end) / $slotDuration);
        $slots = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            $slots[] = [
                $this->formatDate($start),
                $this->formatDate($start->addMinutes($slotDuration)),
            ];
        }

        return $slots;
    }
}
```

#### `index.php`

```php
$slots = Calendar::create()
    ->withBusinessHours([
        ['09:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        ['14:00:00', '18:00:00'],
        // ['18:30:00', '19:00:00'],
    ])
    ->withAppointments([
        ['10:00:00', '10:30:00'],
        ['15:30:00', '16:15:00'],
    ])
    ->getSlots();
```

Comment: Wow, really amazed by your answer. Thank you so much! It works for timeslots of 15 minutes, which is totally what I asked. However I forgot to mention that durations are different for each service. I tried adjusting the slotDuration to 45 as well as 20, but anything other than 15 and it stops working correctly. Once again I really appriciated your work! But what changes are needed in order to make it work with other slotDurations? The slotDurations will always exist of 5 minutes steps.

Comment: @Acework I fixed two issues: I had forgot to replace the hard-coded 15 minutes duration with the dynamic one, and I had also forgot to convert the result of `$start->diffInMinutes($end) / $slotDuration` to an integer instead of a float. Because of this, the loop was generating one slot too many, for each period.

Comment: Excellent post and great logic! I believe what is missing here is if the $slotDuration is > the number of minutes calculated in the diffInMinutes the process fails. For example, if the available time is 75 minutes but the $slotDuration is 90 minutes, the program (as written) returns an erroneous number of slots. I added a simple round down function (precision = 0) and an if statement to only run if $slotCount > 0 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi @EnzoInnocenzi, your answers is working great, the only thing is that the "withBusinessHours" is expecting an array more than 1, if you send a single array errors out. For businesses that hours are straight without breaks, trying to see how be adjusted to fix this.

Comment: Your code has a bug. In case if there is no break, there will be an error in getAvailabilityArray func. Just return business hours (i.e. whole day) in case if there is no break

 if(empty($breaks)) {
            return $this->businessHours;
        }